# How to execute Javascript function defined in main window from within Ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I have Javascript function defined in the main index.html file. 
One part of this page is updated using Ajax (with prototype.js). Attempt to execute Javasript function defined in the main file from within returned AJAX code fails. 
evalScripts: true option in Ajax.Updater prototype.js function does not help.
How do I fix this? Thank you in advance.

This is my index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/lib/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo(x) {
        alert(x);
    }

    function loadContent() {
      new Ajax.Updater('responseArea', 'response.php' , { evalScripts: true } );
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <span style="cursor: pointer" onclick="loadContent();">Click on me to call Ajax response</span><br>
        <br></br>
    </div>

    <div id="responseArea">
        This will be replaced with Ajax response
    </div>
</body>
</html>


This is response.php:
  <?php
         echo '<span style="cursor: pointer" onclick="foo("foo Called from within Ajax response");">
             Click on me to call foo from within Ajax response</span>';
   ?>
```

Comment: you need to escape those double quotes in your echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `evalScripts` is `true`, you can put any JS snippet in your response and it will be executed when the AJAX call completes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
foo("foo Called from within Ajax response");
</script>
```

If you don't want to execute, but just want to include more JS, you can insert a regular JS include tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript src="yournewcode.js"></script>
```

This is better than including the JS inline because it allows the browser to cache the file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried that and it works. But not exactly the way it was supposed to - it executes all scripts in the response code right away. I wanted these functions to be accessible from within AJAX response but not necessary execute them all after the AJAX call completes. For example in the response.php code the foo function is supposed to execute when user clicks on span. Now it just executes immediately. Is there any way of fixing it?

Comment: Than you for your addition. I tried that - but it didn't work. Here is my response.php file now:       <br><?php
 echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="f.js"></script>
   Ajax response <span style="cursor: pointer" onclick="ff("ff Called from within Ajax response");">
             Click on me to call foo from within Ajax response</span>';
   ?> And this is f.js:    function ff(x) {
  alert(x);
    }

Comment: Use Firebug or some other debugger open the NET tab and watch to see if your JS get added to the DOM after the AJAX call or if you get a 404 error.

Comment: Firebug shows neither - it shows successful call to response.php and NO calls to f.js. This is strange since I included <script type="text/javascript" src="f.js"></script> into my AJAX response.

Comment: You can also write some JS to append the script tag to the page header and set the SRC in code.

Comment: It works now! Apparently I misunderstood your advise on JS include tag - I was inserting it into AJAX response rather than into main file. Once I tried to insert it into main file it worked! I appreciate your help, time and expertise so much! You saved my day!